# Cannot locate all audio files to store in list view

Tags: java, android, listview, audio, audio-player

so I am having trouble locating where in my code I have gone wrong. I am building an audio player. The function cannot find all audio files in my device except 2 of them. I am thinking the problem may lie somewhere in my song locating algorithm, findSongs.

Here is my log cat:

```
    03-17 15:29:24.492  20066-20066/? I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , priority [3] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SGH-M919_4.4.4_0048
03-17 15:29:24.492  20066-20066/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> Normal User
03-17 15:29:24.492  20066-20066/? E/dalvikvm﹕ >>>>> com.example.joe.audiodomain [ userId:0 | appId:10237 ]
03-17 15:29:24.492  20066-20066/? D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-17 15:29:24.632  20066-20066/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
03-17 15:29:24.632  20066-20066/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
03-17 15:29:24.632  20066-20066/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15027: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
03-17 15:29:24.632  20066-20066/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-17 15:29:24.632  20066-20066/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
03-17 15:29:24.632  20066-20066/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve interface method 15031: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
03-17 15:29:24.632  20066-20066/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
03-17 15:29:24.702  20066-20066/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
03-17 15:29:24.702  20066-20066/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 396: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
03-17 15:29:24.702  20066-20066/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-17 15:29:24.702  20066-20066/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
03-17 15:29:24.702  20066-20066/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 418: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
03-17 15:29:24.702  20066-20066/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
03-17 15:29:24.712  20066-20066/? E/VdcInflateDelegate﹕ Exception while inflating <vector>
    org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17<vector> tag requires viewportWidth > 0
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:535)
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
            at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:829)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:303)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:178)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.audiodomain.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 15:29:24.712  20066-20066/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
03-17 15:29:24.712  20066-20066/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41845da0)
03-17 15:29:24.712  20066-20066/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.joe.audiodomain, PID: 20066
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.joe.audiodomain/com.example.joe.audiodomain.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.audiodomain.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.audiodomain.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v19/abc_ic_ab_back_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020016
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3439)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1893)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.audiodomain.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3435)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1893)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.superGetDrawable(TintResources.java:48)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.onDrawableLoadedFromResources(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:374)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.getDrawable(TintResources.java:44)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:173)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:60)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:254)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:379)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:300)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:264)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
            at com.example.joe.audiodomain.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5585)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 15:29:31.839  20066-20066/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 20066 SIG: 9
```

Here is my code: 
`

```
    package com.example.joe.mp3demo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String songs[];
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
        //Creating a List view instance
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        //Array list to hold all songs, using findSongs method passing the SD card directory
        ArrayList<File> allSongs= findSongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        songs= new String[allSongs.size()];
        for(int c=0; c< allSongs.size(); c++){
            songs[c]=allSongs.get(c).getName().toString();
        }
        adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, songs);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    //function to find all songs in SD card. Storing them in a temp ArrayList and returning
    public ArrayList<File> findSongs(File root){
        ArrayList<File> al= new ArrayList<File>();
        File[] files=root.listFiles();
        for(File singleFile: files){
            if(singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
                al.addAll(findSongs(singleFile));
            }
            else{
                if(singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wav") || singleFile.getName().endsWith(".wma") ){
                    al.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }

        return al;
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `endsWith` case sensitive?

Comment: yeah i'm sure. hmmmm

Comment: endsWith is case sensitive but, it should, in theory, still grab every file with those ending extensions.

Comment: There is at least one other extension for music files: **m4a** Please look up some extensions of files which were not listed by your app and post them here.

Comment: Thats not the problem, the problem is that I have hundreds of .wav and .mp3 files on my directories and only 2 of them show up on my list.

Comment: @0X0nosugar  Thats not the problem, the problem is that I have hundreds of .wav and .mp3 files on my directories and only 2 of them show up on my list.

Comment: OK, thank you. There's one other possible problem I can think of: you mentioned "directories" (plural) Are the two songs which your app manages to find somehow special ? Do they share the same directory?

Comment: Na, they don't share the same directory. So I don't find anything special about these files.  That is why I am having a hard time trying to figure out what is wrong with it.  Thank you for your help @0x0nosugar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
public class FindMp3Files extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView mp3List;

    String title, artist, path, displayName, songDuration;
    ArrayList<Mp3Model> songs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_mp3_files);

        mp3List = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mp3List);
        songs = new ArrayList<>();

        scanSdcard();

        SongAdapter adapter = new SongAdapter(this, songs);
        mp3List.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void scanSdcard() {
        String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " != 0";
        String[] projection = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
        };
        final String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            Uri uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, null, sortOrder);
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

                    Mp3Model mp3Model = new Mp3Model();

                    title = cursor.getString(0);
                    artist = cursor.getString(1);
                    path = cursor.getString(2);
                    displayName = cursor.getString(3);
                    songDuration = cursor.getString(4);

                    mp3Model.setTitle(title);
                    mp3Model.setArtist(artist);
                    mp3Model.setPath(path);
                    mp3Model.setDisplayName(displayName);
                    mp3Model.setSongDuration(songDuration);

                    songs.add(mp3Model);

                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Tag", e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Mp3Model class :-

```
public class Mp3Model {

    String title, artist, path, displayName, songDuration;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }

    public void setArtist(String artist) {
        this.artist = artist;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }

    public String getSongDuration() {
        return songDuration;
    }

    public void setSongDuration(String songDuration) {
        this.songDuration = songDuration;
    }
}
```

> SongAdapter.java

```
public class SongAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList<Mp3Model> mp3Models;
LayoutInflater inflater;
Typeface captureFont;

public SongAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Mp3Model> mp3Models) {
    this.context = context;
    this.mp3Models = mp3Models;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    captureFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.context.getAssets(), "fonts/Montserrat.ttf");
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mp3Models.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView songName;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder vh;
    if (convertView == null) {
        vh = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.song_row, parent, false);
        vh.songName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songName);
        convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    vh.songName.setText(mp3Models.get(position).getTitle());
    vh.songName.setTypeface(captureFont);
    vh.songName.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    vh.songName.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    vh.songName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#333333"));
    vh.songName.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
    return convertView;
}
}
```

Comment: Whoah, did you just write that?

Comment: Damn. The code I wrote took me hours. Well, can you see what is wrong with my code? I'm not sure I completely understand using the MediaStore stuff, so that is why I went about doing it the way I did it.

Comment: I tried your version of the mp3 player, but did not work. @i_m_mahii

Comment: But it works perfect in my device. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not sure. it just crashes. Maybe im building the song adapter wrong. You did not provide the songAdapter class.

Comment: Give permission in AndroidManifest :-    


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: i added Songadapter class in my answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that song adapter!

Comment: I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: hey! sorry, i've been MIA. So I just tried your code and it crashes on me when I test it.

Comment: It will be up on top

Comment: It is now on top  @i_m_mahii